# Link: Response Header VS HTML

Tags: html, http, hyperlink, header, http-headers

I am currently working on a function to assist in preparing `Link:` HTTP header or a set of `<link>` tags and while reading different materials on this, I still am not able to find an answer to simple question: when to use `Link:` header and when to use `<link>`.
So far I can only say, that if you want to use HTTP20 server push, it is recommended to utilize the header. On the other hand, even if I push a stylesheet, it will not be applied unless there is a respective tag in HTML output.
Since I am preparing the library in order to help with some standardization and sanitization, I would like to catch, at least, some "weird" cases like this, if it's possible, but for that I need some set of recommendations or best practices in that regard. Sadly I am unable to find any thus far, so am turning to more knowledgeable people: what best practices or weird cases should I consider catching or should I just allow whatever to be sent regardless of whether it's a header or a tag?

If anyone is interested, the code is present in https://github.com/Simbiat/HTTP20/blob/main/src/Headers.php (`links` function).

Comment: There are no hard rules for when to use either, because believe they are semantically equivalent. Not every client will support either the header or the html tag, so it depends more on who do you want to support. [my client](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting) supports both, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are supposed to be equivalent as @Evert states so in theory you can use either. However there are some considerations:

Headers are usually set in web server config (at least for static pages) which may not be as easy to update for developers.

However it has the added advantage that you can set these for multiple pages all at once (e.g. preload your core fonts on every .html file, rather than having to remember to set this on all pages, or all page templates if using a CMS).

On the other side with the HTML version it’s often easier to configure it per page (or page template), if you have different needs (e.g. different fonts are used in different pages).

There’s also some which say there are slight performance considerations to doing it in the header but honestly, as long as it’s high enough in the `<HEAD>` element I really think you’d struggle to notice this.

Of perhaps of more importance is whether it’s passed on hop to hop if your web server is hidden behind other infrastructure (e.g. a CDN or other proxy). In theory it should be, for simple headers, but for things like HTTP/2 push that’s not so easy. If it’s in the HTML you don’t need to worry about this (assuming intermediaries are not changing the markup of course!).

You mentioned the HTTP/2 push use case and that definitely needs the header (though this is not a defined standard method of setting push and some servers or CDNs use other methods, but many use this). However given HTTP/2 push’s complexities and concerns it can cause more problems than it solves, this is maybe a reason to recommend the HTML method to ensure it’s never pushed.

All in all I recommend setting this in the HTML. It’s just easier.

This is not the case however with other, similar things, which can be set in HTML and HTTP headers. CSP for example is limited in the HTML version, lacking some features of the HTTP Header version, and is also not recommended as it could be altered with JavaScript whereas the HTTP header cannot. But for simple Link headers these are less of a concern.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response like this. It is largely in line with what I am thinking. Not marking it as an accepted answer for now, in case someone will share some interesting weirdness.